# How can I capture script errors when executed under jsdom?

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I'm using jsdom (in unit tests) to execute some scripts as if they were in a browser, which works great except that if there's an error in one of the scripts, the script fails silently.

The docs indicate that the callback will return an array of errors if any exists, but I'm getting back null, even though I have errors.

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

jsdom.env({
  html: '<html><body></body></html>',
  src: ["throw new Error('something ...')"],
  done: function(errors, window) {
    console.log(errors);
  }
});
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this appears to be a bug.  If you output `window.document.errors` it should show you the  error message.  I've created a new issue [[here](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/644)].